# How to get proper indentation from sass to css?

Tags: css

I am a new sass user. when i am typing in `style.scss` and it converted to `style.css`, the stylesheet indentations is too poor. 
The style.css did not get the proper indentation.

I am using [c9.io](http://c9.io)
here is the [screenshot](http://prntscr.com/c6i06s) of my `style.scss` and `style.css`

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

That is just how SASS compiles, every parent's child will be indented.

You can see how ***panel-heading***, ***thumbnails***, ***panel-footer*** classes are direct children to ***featured_post*** class and they are on same indent level.

Comment: Thank You.
but is there any way to make that css beautiful.

Comment: Yes, there are several options: nested, compact, expanded and compressed.
Check out this [link](https://web-design-weekly.com/2014/06/15/different-sass-output-styles/)